# Minha função em Javascript não está sendo "enxergada"

Tags: javascript, html, submenu

Estou implantando funcionalidades em Javascript para fechar um submenu. Para fechar com ESC e clicando no item de menu que abriu o submenu está funcionado. O que não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar é a função que captura o click fora das áreas do submenu aberto e do item de menu, parece que a função nem está sendo lida. Segue código abaixo para conferência, críticas e sugestões. Sou iniciante e ainda não estou familiarizado com as boas práticas de programação, então fiquem à vontade para criticar o que estiver em desalinho às boas práticas.

**Detalhes:** a parte de HTML e CSS foi copiada de um exemplo, o que fiz foi mudar o nome de algumas classes/Ids mas o código Javascript foi implantado por mim. Havia postado o código no do Codepen, copiei e colei aqui, então está tudo como se fosse um arquivo só. Caso queiram ver no Codepen, o link é esse [Link para o Codepen][1] (nem sei se posso postar o link aqui, então se estiver infringindo as regras, por favor me desculpem).
EDIT: conforme pedido nos comentários, coloquei o código em ordem. A parte de Javascript que está dando problemas fica bem no final, onde tem o Alert("cliquei fora do menu").

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Java/script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <ul>  
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>                                                         <!-- <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Menu_Principal_ITENS" onclick="SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA('SubMenus_MONTAGEM')">Clique-me</a>
          <div id="SubMenus_MONTAGEM">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>    
        </li>
      </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, #Menu_Principal_ITENS {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover #Menu_Principal_ITENS {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM {
    display: none;
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    /* text-align: center; */
    text-align: left;
}

#SubMenus_MONTAGEM a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.CSS_Exibe_Oculta {
display:block;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA(menu){
var obj=document.getElementById(menu);
  if(obj.style.display == 'block'){
    obj.style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else 
  {obj.style.display = 'block';
  }

  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    var tecla = event.keyCode;
    if (tecla == 27){      
      obj.style.display = 'none';
    }    
  });
}

var modal = document.getElementById('menu');
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    alert("cliquei fora do menu");
  }
}
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada no código que vc postou na pergunta. Está tudo desorganizado. Por favor, edite a pergunta com o código bem organizadinho para que se possa analisar melhor.

Comment: Tens razão Sam, ficou desorganizado mesmo, é que copiei do Codepen e fui colando meio que com pressa, agora ficou tudo separado. A parte do código que não está executando é bem no final, onde tem o Alert, que coloquei justamente para ver que essa parte do código não está sendo executada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar o EventListener referente ao body, fora do escopo da função 'SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA' alterando também alguns comandos:

```
function SubMenu_EXIBE_OCULTA(menu){
  var obj=document.getElementById(menu);
  if(obj.style.display == 'block'){
    obj.style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else {
    obj.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var obj = document.getElementById('SubMenus_MONTAGEM');
  var tecla = event.keyCode;
  if(tecla == 27 && obj.style.display == 'block'){
    obj.style.display = 'none';
  }  
});
```

Comment: Olá Caio, desculpa a demora em responder. Fiz isso mas não adiantou, acabei desistindo desse exemplo, estou tentando um novo e já estou com um problema que acho que vou postar aqui. Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.